# The relation between the intersection of two subspaces and the sum of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or give a counter example: Let $W$ and $U$ are two sub spaces of $V$ and $x \in V$. If $x \notin W$ and $x \notin U$, then $x \notin W+U$.

So far I’m trying to disprove this problem by using the fact that the sum of two subsets is bigger than the intersection of U and W, but I’m not completely confident in this approach. Any advice?

Comment: Think about the logic first.  To disprove the statement you do not need to use any general facts ("the sum of two subsets is bigger than the intersection"), you just need to give one example where the result is not true.  Hint: there are easy examples with $V=\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: I believe I made some progress, so when V is a vector in the field $R^2$. Then $(0,1) \in W$ and $(1,0) \in U$. So, $ (0,1) + (1,0) = (1,1) \in W+U$,

Comment: Looks like a good set-up.  Now you need to be clear about what is your vector $x$, what are your subspaces $U$ and $W$, and how this shows the statement is false.  Keep on thinking about the logic: to show "if $A$ then $B$" is false, you need an example where $A$ is true and $B$ is false.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  In $\Bbb R^2$.  How about $W$ is the $x$-axis,  $U$ the $y$-axis?  Consider $x=(1,1)$.

(Ahh, I see you came up with this example.   You just hadn't specified $W$ and $U$.)